# How to exec a local binary in a script in docker image bash?

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I want to use the official bash to run my unit tests but can't exec any local file in a script. Here is a minimal example what I want to do:

```
$ docker run -it bash
bash-4.4# cd /usr/local/bin/
bash-4.4# ./bashbug --version
GNU bashbug, version 4.4.19-release
bash-4.4# echo \#\!/usr/local/bin/bash \
> ./bashbug --version > script.sh
bash-4.4# chmod a+x script.sh
bash-4.4# ./script.sh
/usr/local/bin/bash: ./bashbug --version: No such file or directory
bash-4.4#
```

I one of the installed programs (`/usr/local/bin/bashbug`) to illustrate the problem. As you can see, you can exec `./bashbug` directly, but not when it is executed by a bash script. How can I call it within `script.sh`?

## Edit

The example above has a bug. This is fixed by the accepted answer.

I found out that my original problem was a problem with link dependencies, which outputs:

```
./exec_test.sh: line 30: ./test: No such file or directory
```

When I call `ldd` on `test` I get:

```
ldd test
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe7ad476000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe7ad476000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe7ad476000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /path/bin/gcc-8.1.0/debug/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7fe7ac855000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe7ad476000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /path/bin/gcc-8.1.0/debug/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7fe7ac63d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe7ad476000)
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /path/bin/gcc-8.1.0/debug/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe7ab49b000)
    libboost_system.so.1.67.0 => /path/bin/gcc-8.1.0/debug/libboost_system.so.1.67.0 (0x7fe7ab291000)
Error relocating /path/bin/gcc-8.1.0/debug/libstdc++.so.6: __cxa_thread_atexit_impl: symbol not found
Error relocating /path/bin/gcc-8.1.0/debug/libgcc_s.so.1: __cpu_indicator_init: symbol not found
Error relocating /path/bin/gcc-8.1.0/debug/libgcc_s.so.1: __cpu_model: symbol not found
```

Probably a `glibc` version issue.

Comment: The problem will be immediately obvious if you run `cat script.sh`. You need to put the command to run on a separate line, while now you're just writing it on the line with the shebang

Comment: Thanks, then my minimal example is wrong. I will create a better wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for a here document.

```
cat <<\: >script
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
./bashbug --version
:
```

As an aside, using an `.sh` extension is not generally recommended.